# what is the plus(+) in jquery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I see this selector

```
       $( 'a + .firstSection a' ).live( 'click', function(){
```

in my js file.
What is the purpose of the + sign here?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ and more specifically http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/

Comment: ^^ It's well explained in the documentation ^^

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From jquery doc:

> Selects all next elements matching "next" that are immediately
>   preceded by a sibling "prev". A selector to match the element that is
>   next to the first selector.

Read more about [`prev + next`](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/) selector

Answer (score 0):

1. Browse [the jQuery Docs on Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
2. Find [Next Adjacent Selector (“prev + next”)](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/)
3. Read it

   > Selects all next elements matching "next" that are immediately
   >   preceded by a sibling "prev".

   *Note: even if you don't understand this (and the example!), now you have keywords to search on!*

Comment: I did not know about the keywords prev and next, otherwise I would have read the docs before your suggestion.

Comment: @DoGood But you knew about the docs. There is a Selectors page. You hit Ctrl+F, type `+` and voila. I mean no insult, I'm trying to help you for the future. I use the docs on a daily basis even though I consider myself an advanced jQuery user. It is very useful.

Comment: I didn't expect that searching "+" on the selector page would give me the answer (actually there are only 13 "+" signs on the page, I thought there were more), and searching on google lead me to this question, so I guess it doesn't deserve your tone. +1 for the question, -1 for this answer.

Comment: @Julien I don't really care much about the downvote, but could you honestly explain what is wrong with my tone, sir? I tried to teach him how to fish. This site is not really meant for "Read the manual" type of questions, `Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers`. I can only suggest to you what I suggested to the OP: show some respect to other people and put a minimal effort into solving your problems. Ask questions when you are stuck, not when you are too lazy to find the answer. Be creative, you are (or intend to be) a bloody programmer...

Comment: I found your tone quite arrogant. To me it's not being lazy not to read the doc (it takes less time than writing a question). I was looking for the same kind of information and I found this question which helped me a lot : even if SO is for enthusiast programmers, it also helps finding answers on Google. You're right to teach him to fish, but I think it could have been done more politely.

Comment: I looked up this question, because it was not clear what a + was doing in a selector.  I did a quick look in the docs and did not find it.  I down voted this answer because of your attitude about reading the manual.  I firmly believe that no questions are stupid ones.

Comment: @TayloredWebSites I have no problem with the downvote, you're free to use it. If you were unable to find it in the docs, I feel sorry. I just followed the first link in my question (just to check), hit CTRL+F and then enter "+" (as I mentioned in the comments, but not everybody reads them, I know). I succeeded, I found the selector. I still think my answer is much more useful than the other one.